# How does this conditional part work?

Tags: c, for-loop

In this program, there are two `for` loops. In every `for` loop the conditional part is `text[i][0]` and `text[i][j]`. I don't understand this kind of conditional part. How is this is run or how does it work?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char text[][80] = {

    "When","in","the",
    "course","of","human",
    "events",""
    };

    int i,j;

    for(i=0; text[i][0]; i++){
        for(j=0; text[i][j]; j++)
            printf("%c", text[i][j]);
        printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n%c", text[0][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What's in slot-zero of a C string that has zero length?

Comment: The first loop loops over each word. The second loop loops over each letter. When second loop is done a space is added.

Comment: Using `printf()` with `"%c"` in a loop to print out each character of a string is ... not very sensible.  It should be a single call to `printf("%s", test[i]);` rather than a loop.  However, the looping has pedagogic purposes, so it can survive in the homework — but don't write code like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all loops, the test is whether or not the condition evaluates to true; the loop continues unless the condition evaluates to false or zero.

In the first loop, the condition is equivalent to:

```
test[i][0] != 0
```

which might also be written:

```
test[i] != '\0'
```

since `test[i]` is a `char *` and `test[i][0]` is the first character in the string and the data is initialized with an empty string `""` as the last entry in the array, so the only character in that string is `'\0'`.

In the second loop, the condition checks whether:

```
test[i][j]` != 0;   // Or '\0'
```

This evaluates to false when the end of the string is reached.  The whole of the inner loop would be better replace by a simple:

```
printf("%s ", test[i]);
```

It might be better to omit the trailing blank; there are many ways to do that, but they all involve a test or assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It will loop till it find end of char array `'\0'` in  `text[i][0]` and  `text[i][j]`.
`'\0'` behaves as `false` in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`for(i=0; text[i][0]; i++)` in this loop it says in English that keep looping until the first element of a string is null-terminated which `'\0'`-> in hex `0x00`. Since it is zero it finished the loop. So the string, in your case, should be `""`.

`for(j=0; text[i][j]; j++)` in this loop it says in English that keep looping until the last element of a string null-teminated.

Overall the whole loop says that iterate through all strings one by one until you see `""`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer** : It's a simple concept of handling nested loops.

Explanation :

```
char text[][80] = {

    "When","in","the",
    "course","of","human",
    "events",""
    };
```

it is a declaration of a 2-D array having MAX char length of 80 characters.

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 ..........79
     W  h  e  n
     i  n
     t  h  e
     c  o  u  r  s  e
     o  f
     h  u  m  a  n
     e  v  e  n  t  s
    " "
```

As we know that in a 2-D array, it's not mandatory to define the number of rows but the numbers of columns. That is nothing but the last parameters(i.e 80 in this example).

```
for(i=0; text[i][0]; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; text[i][j]; j++)
        {
         printf("%c", text[i][j]);
         printf(" ");
        }
    }
```

The outer loop is used to iterate the numbers of rows, while the inner loop is used to iterate the numbers of columns.

so text[i][j] value can be easily understood with observing each iteration and with the above table.

I would suggest go through the concepts of nesting loops in order to avoid these kinds of confusion in future.